# how can you automatically show a div based on scrolling

Tags: jquery, css

I have a need to have 10 "steps" of content on a page.  they are all grouped in individual divs but the content is to much.

I want to have the divs auto show if they appear on in the visible browser window.

I have jquery and bootstrap frameworks already in place - I can not find an example or way to figure out how to do this.

Thanks in advance.
Matt

Comment: This question is too broad.  If you have a specific, limited scope, issue that you are having trouble solving, please ask about that issue.  Otherwise please review [ask] for more information.

Comment: hey could you post your code or a codepen/jsfiddle?

Answer (score 0):

you could try the waypoints plugin: http://imakewebthings.com/waypoints/guides/getting-started/. We have used this on on our site for only loading content once in the viewport.